# SQl Query : how to aggregate on part of date

Tags: sql, jet

I am puzzling how to do this in SQL (Jet flavored).. It is beyond my basic SQL skills.

I have a reporting requirement to produce a list of products bought (ie. product name), and the sum of the number of those items bought. Easy so far, but I also need the result aggregated by calendar month to produce something similar to table below :

```
         AUG  JUL JUN JUL 
widgets  23   54  67  67 .....
gadjets  12   34  33  19 .....
```

- **Orders** table has a field called **order_date**
- **Order_Items** table has fields product_name and **items_purchased_count**
- The two tables join on **order_id**

Can someone help ? Is this even possible in a single query ? I have tried a number of things but can't get close.

Thanks in advance.
Bazza

Comment: Thanks for formatting Filipe!

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if something like this would work (don't know much about Jet):

```
select
    oi.product_name,
    sum(iif(month(o.order_date) = 1, oi.items_purchased_count, 0)) as JAN,
    sum(iif(month(o.order_date) = 2, oi.items_purchased_count, 0)) as FEB,
    ...
from orders o
inner join order_items oi on o.order_id = oi.order_id
group by oi.product_name
```